# How Do I Find WiFi Settings?

Tags: wireless, 13.04

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.04 in an old Dell Laptop. I am only using Ubuntu in this old laptop.

I am not picking up the wireless signal from my wireless router.

Where is the selection menu in Ubuntu? Is this a possible fault of the laptop?

I just wiped out Windows Vista. Is a driver missing for the wireless?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked whether the hardware wireless switch is working? If yes, is it on?

Comment: Do some basic diagnostics. From command line (Ctrl-Alt-T), type **`sudo lshw`**. *You may need a driver, before WiFi is working.* What is the wireless brand/model?